# Looking for a convenient way to create hard links

Tags: linux, hard-link

I'm looking for a convenient way to create hard links. Sort of like a drag and drop method. I was looking for such a feature in Midnight Commander but I couldn't find it. If there's a CLI-based file manager that can do such a thing, please make it known to me!

My use case: I have a server running a web based BitTorrent client and Plex. I want to be able to create hard links from my media files that I've downloaded to a folder that Plex is watching. I don't want to use symbolic links because I just want to delete the torrent + files in the client without worrying about it.

I realize that I can do this from the command line, but it's just tedious typing out the commands when you have multiple folders with files that you want to hard link.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because you want don't want to use command line, but if you learn more about inotify (and inotifywait) you can automate the creation of hard links and never worry about it again. It would be better than even a drag and drop solution. ;)

Comment: What distro are you using?  Also what desktop environment and what file browser?